# Wall Climbing Dynamic program

Tags: dynamic-programming

[image]

How do i solve this? I am not sure where to start.
I am trying to define a Optimum solution which i can use to create a dynamic program. I am not sure what the characteristics of the optimum should be. 
right now i am thinking, 
at any instance of the problem, we know, the person will move right , left or up.( He can't always move up, only when near a ladder) 
How to I follow this??
any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: this is a site where one can ask questions in order to learn.  You have not asked a question, but posted a problem.  As a very minimum, we need you to write in your own words what you are trying to do, and _where you are stuck_.  How do you expect us to explain something to you when we don't know what it is you understand and what it is you don't understand?  This question will be closed and un-answered unless you put in some effort.

Comment: By all means, properly attribute quoted material. Please do not present text as a pixel raster: cut&paste it as a *block quote*.

Comment: @rspenpal, could you please cite the source of this exercise?

Comment: The problem statement appears to be pasted from [U Washington's CSE 421](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse421/20sp/), [Homework 6](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse421/20sp/hw6.pdf), Problem P2.   [Copying without attribution](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) is [not cool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83955/plagiarism-should-be-addressed-specifically-in-the-faq/134715#134715).

Answer (score 1):

I will assume $n>0$. Let $d_i(a)$ be the minimum number of moves needed to start from position $(a, i)$ and collect  the coins at coordinates $(x_i, i)$ and $(y_i, i)$.
$$
d_i(a) = \min \{ |x_i-a| + |y_i-x_i|, |y_i-a| + |x_i-y_i|\}
$$

Similarly, let $d_i(a,b)$ be the minimum number of moves needed to start from position $(a, i)$ and reach position $(b,i)$ while collecting the coins on coordinates $(x_i, i)$ and $(y_i, i)$. 
$$
d_i(a,b) = \min \{ |x_i-a| + |y_i-x_i| + |b-y_i|, |y_i-a| + |x_i-y_i| + |b-x_i|\}
$$

For $j \in \{1, 2\}$, let $OPT_j[i]$ be the minimum number of moves needed  to start from position $(0,0)$  and reach position $(z_j, i)$ while  collecting all the coins at heights up to $i$. According to this definition
$
OPT_j[0] = d_0(0, z_j)
$ and, for $i = 1, \dots, n$:
$$
OPT_j[i] = 1 + \min_{h \in \{1,2\}}\{ OPT_h[i-1] + d_i(z_h, z_j) \}.
$$

The optimal solution is then $1 + \min_{h \in \{1,2\}} \{OPT_h[n-1] + d(z_h)  \}$.

This algorithm can be implemented to run in $O(n)$ time since there are $O(n)$ subproblems and each subproblem can be solved in constant time (once the solutions to the previous subproblems are known).